# Transformation of $x = q+x^m$ to $x^α-x^β=(α-β)vx^{α+β}$

Tags: linear-algebra

In the paper [On the Lambert W Function](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf), the first page says Euler transformed $x = q+x^m$ to $x^α-x^β=(α-β)vx^{α+β}$ by substituting $x^{−β}$ for $x$ and setting $m = αβ$ and $q = (α − β)v$.

I am trying to derive $x^α-x^β=(α-β)vx^{α+β}$ from $x=q+x^m$ but failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a typo, I believe the change is $\color{red}{\beta m = \alpha}$. Call $x = y^{-\beta}$, so that $x = q + x^m$ transforms to

$$
y^{-\beta} = q + y^{-\beta m} = q + y^{-\alpha} \tag{1}
$$

Now multiply both sides by $y^{\alpha + \beta}$ and you get

$$
y^{\alpha} = q y^{\alpha + \beta} + y^{\beta} \tag{2}
$$

And replace $q = (\alpha - \beta)v$ to get

$$
y^{\alpha} - y^{\beta} = (\alpha - \beta)v y^{\alpha + \beta} \tag{3}
$$